# How to implement IHttpFactoryClient in examples of Typed HttpClient?

Tags: c#, .net, rest, httpclient, httpclientfactory

In every example I've seen, including the Microsoft ones [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-3.1#typed-clients) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests), the author's explain the improvements made by `IHttpClientFactory` over `HttpClient` and give examples of how to use it simply out-of-the-box or in Named form. But then they all seem to mention that utilizing the Typed form really is best for its structure, usability, and more. The reasons make sense for our use case.

Though like the links provided above, there isn't a single line of code instantiating, injecting, or using `IHttpClientFactory` in the involvement of creating a Typed `HttpClient` (or Service as a Client). You create the Typed Client:

```
public class GitHubService
{
    public HttpClient Client { get; }

    public GitHubService(HttpClient client)
    {
```

and then you consume it in some model or controller:

```
public TypedClientModel(GitHubService gitHubService)
{
    _gitHubService = gitHubService;
}

public async Task OnGet()
{
    try
    {
        LatestIssues = await _gitHubService.GetAspNetDocsIssues();
    }
```

I'm extremely confused. My team was originally hitting roadblocks trying to mock (with Moq) Typed clients for unit testing, and the conclusion that we came to after many great resources was that mocking was exponentially easier with `IHttpClientFactory`. But I haven't found a single example that explicitly uses `IHttpClientFactory` with Typed clients.

Comment: It might be easier for testing/mocking if you inject an interface of the client instead of the implementation. There's an overload of AddHttpClient that allows registering that way: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.httpclientfactoryservicecollectionextensions.addhttpclient?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1#Microsoft_Extensions_DependencyInjection_HttpClientFactoryServiceCollectionExtensions_AddHttpClient__2_Microsoft_Extensions_DependencyInjection_IServiceCollection_

Comment: Typed clients are a special case and the framework will use the factory to create the HttpClient to be injected into the types client.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The framework will use `ITypedHttpClientFactory` to create the `HttpClient` to be injected into the typed client. This is happening under the hood when the typed client is configured like so:

```
services.AddHttpClient<ICatalogService, CatalogService>()
```

If we peek into `AddHttpClient`, we can see that it'll attempt to create a transient version of `IHttpClientFactory` called `ITypedHttpClientFactory`

```
services.TryAdd(ServiceDescriptor.Transient(typeof(ITypedHttpClientFactory<>), typeof(DefaultTypedHttpClientFactory<>)));
```

Typed clients do also allow for abstracted clients

```
public class GitHubService :IGitHubService { // <-- NOTE THE INTERFACE 
    HttpClient client

    public GitHubService(HttpClient client) {
        this.client = client;
    }

    //...
```

Where the interface is registered along with its implementation using [AddHttpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.httpclientfactoryservicecollectionextensions.addhttpclient)

```
services.AddHttpClient<IGitHubService, GitHubService>();
```

and used accordingly

```
//...

private readonly IGitHubService gitHubService;

public TypedClientModel(IGitHubService gitHubService) {
    this.gitHubService = gitHubService;
}

public async Task OnGet() {
    try {
        LatestIssues = await gitHubService.GetAspNetDocsIssues();
    }

//...
```

The advantage here is that You decouple from 3rd party dependencies (framework concerns) since you are the one in control of the typed client and its abstraction.

This will allow for easier mocking of the typed client abstraction when testing in isolation.

Comment: "the framework will use the factory to create the HttpClient to be injected into the typed client." How? Where? This is the magic that is happening that I am trying to unravel. Articles and sources mention it, but its very hand-wavy.

Comment: @8protons Typed clients are just a convenience pattern applied through DI. You can browse the source code of the extensions and drill down to where the IHttpClientFactory is ultimately registered and used: https://github.com/aspnet/HttpClientFactory/blob/7c4f9479b4753a37c8b0669a883002e5e448cc94/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Http/DependencyInjection/HttpClientFactoryServiceCollectionExtensions.cs#L233

Comment: Here is where it ultimately uses the factory to create the client: https://github.com/aspnet/HttpClientFactory/blob/7c4f9479b4753a37c8b0669a883002e5e448cc94/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Http/DependencyInjection/HttpClientBuilderExtensions.cs#L367

Answer (score 0):

With `IHttpClientFactory` you have three options:

### IHttpClientFactory

#### Usage

```cs
public class SampleController
{
    private readonly IHttpClientFactory _clientFactory;
    public SampleController(IHttpClientFactory clientFactory)
    {
        _clientFactory = clientFactory;
    }
}
```

#### Mocking

```cs
//Arrange
var mockClientFactory = new Mock<IHttpClientFactory>();
var mockMessageHandler = new Mock<HttpMessageHandler>();
mockMessageHandler.Protected()
    .Setup<Task<HttpResponseMessage>>("SendAsync", ItExpr.IsAny<HttpRequestMessage>(), ItExpr.IsAny<CancellationToken>())
    .ReturnsAsync(expectedResponseMessage);

var client = new HttpClient(mockMessageHandler.Object);
mockClientFactory
    .Setup(_ => _.CreateClient(It.IsAny<string>()))
    .Returns(client);
```

### Named client

#### Usage

```cs
public class SampleController
{
    private readonly HttpClient _client;
    public SampleController(IHttpClientFactory clientFactory)
    {
        _client = clientFactory.CreateClient("SampleProxy");
    }
}
```

#### Mocking

As an [alternative](https://hamidmosalla.com/2017/02/08/mock-httpclient-using-httpmessagehandler/) we can avoid the usage of *Moq.Protected* by using a custom `HttpMessageHandler`

```cs
public class FakeMessageHandler: HttpMessageHandler
{
    public virtual HttpResponseMessage Send(HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return Task.FromResult(Send(request));
    }
}
```

```cs
//Arrange
var mockClientFactory = new Mock<IHttpClientFactory>();
var mockMessageHandler = new Mock<FakeMessageHandler> { CallBase = true };
mockMessageHandler
    .Setup(handler => handler.Send(It.IsAny<HttpRequestMessage>()))
    .Returns(expectedResponseMessage);

var client = new HttpClient(mockMessageHandler.Object);
mockClientFactory
    .Setup(_ => _.CreateClient("SampleProxy"))
    .Returns(client);
```

### Typed client

#### Usage

```cs
public class SampleController
{
    private readonly ISampleClient _client;
    public SampleController(ISampleClient client)
    {
        _client = client;
    }
}
```

#### Mocking

```cs
//Arrange
var clientMock = new Mock<ISampleClient>();
clientMock
    .Setup(client => client.GetXYZ(It.IsAny<SampleRequest>()))
    .ReturnsAsync(expectedSampleResponse);

var SUT = new SampleController(clientMock.Object);
```